# Solve an equation and plot the results in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy, solver

Let's assume I have an equation, such as

> 10 * x ** 2 - 7 * x + 3 == 2 * y + y ** 2

I want to solve it for `y`, then plot `y` vs `x` for `x` from 0 to 1. How do I do that in Python?

I know how to do it in Mathematica but I am migrating to Python. In Mathematica it's just one line

```js
Plot[y /. Solve[10 x^2 - 7 x + 3 == 2 y + y^2, y], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sympy's [`plot_implicit()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot_implicit.plot_implicit), you can directly draw the equation.

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, plot_implicit

x, y = symbols('x y')
plot_implicit(Eq(10 * x ** 2 - 7 * x + 3, 2 * y + y ** 2), (x, -1, 2))
```

[image: sympy plot_implicit]

Answer (score 7):

SymPy is a symbolic math package:

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sympy/sympy_quick_guide.htm

```
from sympy import solve, plot
from sympy.abc import x, y

ans = solve(10 * x ** 2 - 7 * x + 3 - (2 * y + y ** 2), y)
print(ans)
```

answer:

```
[-sqrt(10*x**2 - 7*x + 4) - 1, sqrt(10*x**2 - 7*x + 4) - 1]
```

Then you can plot with any plotting package, or with sympy.plot:

```
plot(ans[0])
plot(ans[1])
```